# Why is my PROCHOT value at 85 C?

Tags: intel-core-i7, throttling

I am using ThrottleStop on my laptop (ASUS GL553ve - i7-7700HQ, nvidia gtx 1050ti). The thing is, it throttles my CPU at temperature of 85C, while the max safe operating temperature is like 100C. It can be seen in the picture:

[image: screenshot of ThrottleStop settings]

Why is my PROCHOT value at 85 C?

Answer (score 1):

"This means that your laptop manufacturer decided to ignore Intel's advice and decided to set a lower thermal throttling temperature to either protect some weak components within your laptop or maybe they were just trying to protect your lap. Individual manufacturers are allowed to offset the official thermal throttling temperature by up to 15°C."

Answered by unclewebb on a different board:

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/what-does-the-prochot-95%C2%B0c-do.3301894/

Comment: Is there any way I can increase this value? Will it be safe? While playing games, my CPU temperatures keep hitting 89-90C and it gets throttled. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Not really. Not without some serious hardware or firmware hacking.

Comment: Even if you do get your CPU to only throttle at 99c, you will most likely burn something else in your laptop. (like the soldering of components around the CPU) or force the GPU to throttle down, considering they are using the same cooler.
I would rather suggest actively cooling your laptop while playing.
Maybe you can test this solution https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?97641-GL553VD-opptical-drive-replacement-with-extra-cooling-fan

Comment: @Calin Don't spread misinformation. The solder used on motherboards melts at >300C, not 100C. There's nothing wrong with running hotter other than exceeding touch safe temperature limits on the case